# How does one find a parameter representation for bounded region?

Tags: parametric, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, parametrization

I need help with this question. I have been stuck at it for a few days. My main problem is how I use the curve $K_r$ to find the parametric representation.

I have a curve $K_r$ in the $(x,y)$-plane given by:

$r(u)= (sinh(u),cosh(u))$,  u ∈ [0,2]

I have to find the parametric representation for the bounded region A that is bounded by $K_r$ and the line segments from (2,0) to r(0) and (2,0) to r(2).

This is the plot I have made if it is of any help.
[image: Region in question]

Comment: $cosh^2(t) - sinh^2(t)=1$ and $x=sinh(u)$, $y=cosh(u)$

Comment: Thanks for the info. I still have problems stating the parameter representation.